# Issue with PHP and Javascript when building auto suggest text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to build a simple auto suggest input bar that connects to a MySql database and retrieves data. The issue that I'm running into is that when I type in the name of an object that I know exists in the databse, the text bar doesn't return any results, instead it just provides me with an empty dropdown box.

The best I can tell, the issue has to do with the javascript that is used within the PHP portion of the code. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out why it's causing an issue.

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("host", "user", "passsword") OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
    mysql_select_db('DBName');
    $query = 'SELECT Device_type FROM Device';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $counter = 0;
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo"this.nameArray = new Array()";
    if($result) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo("this.nameArray"  .$row ['Device_type'] . "';");
            $counter += 1;
        }
    }
    echo("</script>");
    ?>
```

When I take out the `echo"<script type='text/javascript'>";` and `echo"this.nameArray = new Array()";` then It displays the Device_type content on the top of the page when the page is loaded. This obviously isn't what I want, but it does prove that the database connection is at least set up correctly. Since this chunk of PHP is referring to some javascript, I will also prove the function in which it's referring to.

```
    function doSuggestions(text) {
        var input = text;
        //window.alert(text);
        var inputLength = input.toString().length;
        var code = "";
        var counter = 0;
        while(counter < this.nameArray.length) {
            var x = this.nameArray[counter]; // avoids retyping this code a bunch of times
            if(x.substr(0, inputLength).toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase()) {
                code += "<div id='" + x + "'onmouseover='changeBG(this.id);' onMouseOut='changeBG(this.id);' onclick='doSelection(this.innerHTML)'>" + x + "</div>";
            }
            counter += 1;
        }
        if(code == "") {
            outClick();
        }
        document.getElementById('divSuggestions').innerHTML = code;
        document.getElementById('divSuggestions').style.overflow='auto';
    }
```

Any suggestions as to why the suggestion box isn't providing suggestions when I start typing? If I type `A` into the text box, the suggestion box should appear showing me all items in the database that start with `A`.

Comment: check this out https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ it can help you

Comment: It might be secretly telling you not to use `mysql_*` anymore and that one morning you will wake up and find that your website is not working anymore due to hackery or deprecation.

Comment: @guradio I've actually seen this, and debated going this direction, but I am looking for something that can connect to a database as I may need to upload large chunks of data to the back end.

Answer (score 0):

there are some errors in your js strings

```
 `echo"var nameArray = new Array()";`
 `echo("nameArray.push('"  .$row ['Device_type'] . "');");`
```

that way you'll push device types into the nameArray var.

Comment: Hmmm, made the change as suggested, but still having the same issue.

Comment: remove `this` from  `while(counter < this.nameArray.length) {` and do the same on `var x = this.nameArray[counter];`

Comment: Still having the same results. I removed it from both lines.

Comment: Any other ideas as to what it could be?